# Clickable Fetched Data: Website Redirect

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, web

Okay, I really don't know now what else to query just to find the right answer for this. I want to do a website redirect from the fetched data. Here's the piece of what I've tried:

```
<td><a href='" . $row['website'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>
```

That clickable data is redirecting me to `http://localhost/systemfolder/www.sampleweb.com`. I tried putting `../../` just in case it works, but it is only redirecting me to `http://localhost/www.sampleweb.com`. I want that fetched data to redirect to `www.sampleweb.com`

How to make that link go outside of the localhost? Do I need to do something more than using the `<a href="">` thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to put in the complete link. Use `http://www.sampleweb.com`
and it will redirect you to the site rather than the same on your domain.

Comment: Oh. Damn it. I forgot about that. I only focused on fetching the data. Thanks for reminding me! Haha

Answer (score 0):

You need a full url to redirect to the website.

replace

```
<td><a href='" . $row['website'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>
```

to

```
<td><a href='http://". $row['website'] . "' target='_blank'>" . $row['website'] . "</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
<td>
<a href="<?php echo $row['website']; ?>" target='_blank'><?php echo $row['website']; ?></a>
</td>
```

**OR**

```
    <td>
    <a href="http://<?php echo $row['website']; ?>" target='_blank'><?php echo $row['website']; ?></a>
    </td>
```